# generate netsuite oauth1 signature bash

Tags: bash, oauth

How can I generate an OAuth1 signature in bash?  I happen to need to talk to NetSuite, but that is not really relevant to my question.  Here is the code I am experimenting with.

```
urlencode () {
        [ -n "$1" ] \
        && echo -n "$1" | perl -p -e 's/([^A-Za-z0-9-._~])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg'
}

url=...
encodedURL=$(urlencode $url)
Realm=...
ConsumerKey=...
encodedConsumerKey=$(urlencode $ConsumerKey)
ConsumerSecret=...
encodedConsumerSecret=$(urlencode $ConsumerSecret)
AccessToken=...
encodedAccessToken=$(urlencode $AccessToken)
TokenSecret=...
encodedTokenSecret=$(urlencode $TokenSecret)
Nonce=$(openssl rand -base64 12)
Nonce="XgxZ3436Kmz"
Timestamp=$(date +%s)
Timestamp="1666202652"
#PARAM=$(urlencode "oauth_consumer_key=$consumer_key&oauth_nonce=$nonce&oauth_signature_method=$signature_method&oauth_timestamp=$timestamp&oauth_token=$AccessToken&oauth_version=1.0")
PARAM=$(urlencode "oauth_consumer_key=$ConsumerKey&oath_nonce=$Nonce&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=$Timestamp&oath_token=$AccessToken&oauth_version=1.0")
encodedPARAM=$(urlencode "oauth_consumer_key=$encodedConsumerKey&oath_nonce=$Nonce&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=$Timestamp&oath_token=$encodedAccessToken&oauth_version=1.0")


signature=$(echo -n 'POST&'$encodedURL'&'$encodedPARAM|openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "$encodedConsumerSecret&$encodedTokenSecret" |base64)
encoded_signature=$(urlencode $signature)
```

In theory, because I am using the same Nonce, Timestamp, ConsumerKey, etc, from PostMan, I should get the same signature, but I am not.  So I must be doing something wrong.  I have tried a few different things.  I started with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gsilos/77109ba9afdde584e6e79e4cfc1c24f2).  I know my keys, secrets, token, and URL work in PostMan, so just trying to do something similar in a bash script.  I know how to get Nonce and Timestamp, although I purposely hardcoded above to mimic the last run in PostMan.  Once I do this for real, the only thing that will change is Nonce and Timestamp.

I have also been looking at another library, but it seems older, so might be outdated: [here](https://github.com/lbarchive/bash-oauth/tree/8973f2b029e8790b73a98670de84465e606cf6ce).  Also still trying to figure it out.  Other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you posted your code to https://shellcheck.net and fixed all the issues found there? Using un-quoted variables is often a source of problems. Also, using `url=...` doesn't give us anyting to test with. It seems like a lot of code to digest for "generate(ing) an oauth signature". Can't you focus in on one problem line? Read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Search for "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: The [spellcheck.net](https://spellcheck.net) did not reveal anything interesting.  Also, I purposely did not include the URL because I am looking for generic steps, and because it reveals stuff publicly I don't want revealed.  Can anyone provide such generic steps?  This is merely the first step, and I am unit testing things to make sure I understand.  Thus comparing a bash produced signature to one from Postman.

Comment: Since it seems there is no solid directions for doing this generically, I went with Python.  For anyone that find this post, asking the same question, there are language bindings for quite a few languages out there, including scripting languages, so try that, maybe.  Also, often there will be a binding to the actual service you are talking to. For instance, in my case there was a Python Netsuite library out there, made my life much easier.

Comment: Good followup. Thanks for sharing your experience and sorry I couldn't help you fix that code. Maybe if I was sitting at your desk (-;  . Good luck.